# When should I use the past simple, the future perfect, and present simple?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, verb-forms, future-tense, past-simple

I'm doing a quiz and have some doubts in a few tasks. Could somebody check if I'm correct?

Ex1. Put the correct form.

As soon as we arrived at the airport, we **checked in**.

a) had checked in
b) were checking in
c) checked in

Explanation. I've chosen here **c** because we have here consecutive actions, i.e. we arrived and then we checked in. Other options don't make sense.

The car **will soon have done** 50,000 km - we'll need to get it serviced.

a) will soon have done
b) will soon do
c) will soon be doing

Explanation. I've chosen here **a** because in this sentence we want to stress that in some short period of time we will get 50,000 km on a odometer. Other options don't make sense as well.

Ex2. Put the verb in a correct form.

Many people have problems sleeping if they **drink** coffee after midday. (drink)

Explanation. I've chosen here present simple because we want to stress avery day action (*they drink coffee*).
I wonder if we could use here present progressive - *Many people have problems sleeping if they **are drinking** coffee after midday*?

I want to spend a year travelling when I **will have finished** university. (finish)

Explanation. I've chosen here a future perfect because that guy probably already have a plan he is going to travel after finishing university, thus he wants to stress it.
But future simple I think also possible.

Comment: Just as a note - this: *The car will soon have done 50,000 km* Must be regional... as an AmE speaker, I would never use the word *done* to mean *traveled*. Also, this is an odometer, not a tachometer. Tachs measure revolutions per minute.

Comment: @Catija oops, my mistake with odometer. Fixed.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to explain why your answer for the fourth one is wrong but I think I should leave it to someone else. The first three are perfectly correct, though.

Comment: @Catija Should I use *future simple* in fourth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Catija, the first three sentences are perfectly OK and as to the last one, the simple present tense is actually the correct usage.

According to grammar, when you are talking about the future, you should use the present simple in the time (when) clause, not a future form. For example, I'll come when I finish my work. So the correct sentence is:

I want to spend a year travelling when I finish university.

(Reference: The Free Dictionary - the use of "when").

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

> I want to spend a year traveling when I [finish] university.

The simple present tense is actually the correct usage here because it's being [used in a subordinate clause](http://www.englishgrammar.org/tenses-subordinate-clauses/):

> I want to spend a year traveling when I finish university.